# Fail2Ban not banning IPs with different ports

Tags: fail2ban

I am getting different SSH attacks from the same IPs and they are getting banned. But they are using a different port and all they have to do is change the port to bypass the ban.

```
Dec 28 23:16:57 Nixie sshd[30706]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 3424 ssh2
Dec 28 23:16:54 Nixie sshd[30704]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 1112 ssh2
Dec 28 23:16:51 Nixie sshd[30702]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 1116 ssh2
Dec 28 23:16:47 Nixie sshd[30700]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 1115 ssh2
Dec 28 23:16:43 Nixie sshd[30698]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 1114 ssh2
Dec 28 23:16:40 Nixie sshd[30696]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 1113 ssh2
Dec 28 23:16:37 Nixie sshd[30694]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 3424 ssh2
Dec 28 23:16:33 Nixie sshd[30692]: Failed password for root from 40.127.178.38 port 1112 ssh2
```

Here is my jail.local:

```
   # Fail2Ban configuration file.    
#    
# This file was composed for Debian systems from the original one    
# provided now under /usr/share/doc/fail2ban/examples/jail.conf    
# for additional examples.    
#    
# Comments: use '#' for comment lines and ';' for inline comments    
#    
# To avoid merges during upgrades DO NOT MODIFY THIS FILE    
# and rather provide your changes in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local    
#    

# The DEFAULT allows a global definition of the options. They can be overridden    
# in each jail afterwards.    

[DEFAULT]    

# "ignoreip" can be an IP address, a CIDR mask or a DNS host. Fail2ban will not    
# ban a host which matches an address in this list. Several addresses can be    
# defined using space separator.    
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8    

# "bantime" is the number of seconds that a host is banned.    
bantime  = 3600    

# A host is banned if it has generated "maxretry" during the last "findtime"    
# seconds.    
findtime = 600    
maxretry = 3    

# "backend" specifies the backend used to get files modification.    
# Available options are "pyinotify", "gamin", "polling" and "auto".    
# This option can be overridden in each jail as well.    
#    
# pyinotify: requires pyinotify (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.    
#            If pyinotify is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.    
# gamin:     requires Gamin (a file alteration monitor) to be installed.    
#            If Gamin is not installed, Fail2ban will use auto.    
# polling:   uses a polling algorithm which does not require external libraries.    
# auto:      will try to use the following backends, in order:    
#            pyinotify, gamin, polling.    
backend = auto    

# "usedns" specifies if jails should trust hostnames in logs,    
#   warn when reverse DNS lookups are performed, or ignore all hostnames in logs    
#    
# yes:   if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed.    
# warn:  if a hostname is encountered, a reverse DNS lookup will be performed,    
#        but it will be logged as a warning.    
# no:    if a hostname is encountered, will not be used for banning,    
#        but it will be logged as info.    
usedns = warn    

#    
# Destination email address used solely for the interpolations in    
# jail.{conf,local} configuration files.    
destemail = root@localhost    

#    
# Name of the sender for mta actions    
sendername = Fail2Ban    

#    
# ACTIONS    
#    

# Default banning action (e.g. iptables, iptables-new,    
# iptables-multiport, shorewall, etc) It is used to define    
# action_* variables. Can be overridden globally or per    
# section within jail.local file    
banaction = iptables-allports    

# email action. Since 0.8.1 upstream fail2ban uses sendmail    
# MTA for the mailing. Change mta configuration parameter to mail    
# if you want to revert to conventional 'mail'.    
mta = sendmail    

# Default protocol    
protocol = tcp    

# Specify chain where jumps would need to be added in iptables-* actions    
chain = INPUT    

#    
# Action shortcuts. To be used to define action parameter    

# The simplest action to take: ban only    
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]    

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.    
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]    
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]    

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines    
# to the destemail.    
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]    
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]    

# Choose default action.  To change, just override value of 'action' with the    
# interpolation to the chosen action shortcut (e.g.  action_mw, action_mwl, etc) in jail.local    
# globally (section [DEFAULT]) or per specific section    
action = %(action_)s    

#    
# JAILS    
#    

# Next jails corresponds to the standard configuration in Fail2ban 0.6 which    
# was shipped in Debian. Enable any defined here jail by including    
#    
# [SECTION_NAME]    
# enabled = true    

#    
# in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.    
#    
# Optionally you may override any other parameter (e.g. banaction,    
# action, port, logpath, etc) in that section within jail.local    

[ssh]    

enabled  = true    
port     = ssh    
filter   = sshd    
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log    
maxretry = 3    

[dropbear]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ssh    
filter   = dropbear    
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log    
maxretry = 6    

# Generic filter for pam. Has to be used with action which bans all ports    
# such as iptables-allports, shorewall    
[pam-generic]    

enabled  = false    
# pam-generic filter can be customized to monitor specific subset of 'tty's    
filter   = pam-generic    
# port actually must be irrelevant but lets leave it all for some possible uses    
port     = all    
banaction = iptables-allports    
port     = anyport    
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log    
maxretry = 6    

[xinetd-fail]    

enabled   = false    
filter    = xinetd-fail    
port      = all    
banaction = iptables-multiport-log    
logpath   = /var/log/daemon.log    
maxretry  = 2    


[ssh-ddos]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ssh    
filter   = sshd-ddos    
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log    
maxretry = 6    


# Here we use blackhole routes for not requiring any additional kernel support    
# to store large volumes of banned IPs    

[ssh-route]    

enabled = false    
filter = sshd    
action = route    
logpath = /var/log/sshd.log    
maxretry = 6    

# Here we use a combination of Netfilter/Iptables and IPsets    
# for storing large volumes of banned IPs    
#    
# IPset comes in two versions. See ipset -V for which one to use    
# requires the ipset package and kernel support.    
[ssh-iptables-ipset4]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ssh    
filter   = sshd    
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto4    
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log    
maxretry = 6    

[ssh-iptables-ipset6]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ssh    
filter   = sshd    
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6    
logpath  = /var/log/sshd.log    
maxretry = 6    


#    
# HTTP servers    
#    

[apache]    

enabled  = false    
port     = http,https    
filter   = apache-auth    
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log    
maxretry = 6    

# default action is now multiport, so apache-multiport jail was left    
# for compatibility with previous (<0.7.6-2) releases    
[apache-multiport]    

enabled   = false    
port      = http,https    
filter    = apache-auth    
logpath   = /var/log/apache*/*error.log    
maxretry  = 6    

[apache-noscript]    

enabled  = false    
port     = http,https    
filter   = apache-noscript    
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log    
maxretry = 6    

[apache-overflows]    

enabled  = false    
port     = http,https    
filter   = apache-overflows    
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*error.log    
maxretry = 2    

# Ban attackers that try to use PHP's URL-fopen() functionality    
# through GET/POST variables. - Experimental, with more than a year    
# of usage in production environments.    

[php-url-fopen]    

enabled = false    
port    = http,https    
filter  = php-url-fopen    
logpath = /var/www/*/logs/access_log    

# A simple PHP-fastcgi jail which works with lighttpd.    
# If you run a lighttpd server, then you probably will    
# find these kinds of messages in your error_log:    
#   ALERT – tried to register forbidden variable ‘GLOBALS’    
#   through GET variables (attacker '1.2.3.4', file '/var/www/default/htdocs/index.php')    

[lighttpd-fastcgi]    

enabled = false    
port    = http,https    
filter  = lighttpd-fastcgi    
logpath = /var/log/lighttpd/error.log    

# Same as above for mod_auth    
# It catches wrong authentifications    

[lighttpd-auth]    

enabled = false    
port    = http,https    
filter  = suhosin    
logpath = /var/log/lighttpd/error.log    

[nginx-http-auth]    

enabled = true    
filter  = nginx-http-auth    
port    = http,https    
logpath = /var/log/nginx/error.log    

# Monitor roundcube server    

[roundcube-auth]    

enabled  = false    
filter   = roundcube-auth    
port     = http,https    
logpath  = /var/log/roundcube/userlogins    


[sogo-auth]    

enabled  = false    
filter   = sogo-auth    
port     = http, https    
# without proxy this would be:    
# port    = 20000    
logpath  = /var/log/sogo/sogo.log    


#    
# FTP servers    
#    

[vsftpd]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data    
filter   = vsftpd    
logpath  = /var/log/vsftpd.log    
# or overwrite it in jails.local to be    
# logpath = /var/log/auth.log    
# if you want to rely on PAM failed login attempts    
# vsftpd's failregex should match both of those formats    
maxretry = 6    


[proftpd]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data    
filter   = proftpd    
logpath  = /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log    
maxretry = 6    


[pure-ftpd]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data    
filter   = pure-ftpd    
logpath  = /var/log/syslog    
maxretry = 6    


[wuftpd]    

enabled  = false    
port     = ftp,ftp-data,ftps,ftps-data    
filter   = wuftpd    
logpath  = /var/log/syslog    
maxretry = 6    


#    
# Mail servers    
#    

[postfix]    

enabled  = false    
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission    
filter   = postfix    
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log    


[couriersmtp]    

enabled  = false    
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission    
filter   = couriersmtp    
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log    


#    
# Mail servers authenticators: might be used for smtp,ftp,imap servers, so    
# all relevant ports get banned    
#    

[courierauth]    

enabled  = false    
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s    
filter   = courierlogin    
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log    


[sasl]    

enabled  = false    
port     = smtp,ssmtp,submission,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s    
filter   = postfix-sasl    
# You might consider monitoring /var/log/mail.warn instead if you are    
# running postfix since it would provide the same log lines at the    
# "warn" level but overall at the smaller filesize.    
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log    

[dovecot]    

enabled = false    
port    = smtp,ssmtp,submission,imap2,imap3,imaps,pop3,pop3s    
filter  = dovecot    
logpath = /var/log/mail.log    

# To log wrong MySQL access attempts add to /etc/my.cnf:    
# log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log    
# log-warning = 2    
[mysqld-auth]    

enabled  = false    
filter   = mysqld-auth    
port     = 3306    
logpath  = /var/log/mysqld.log    


# DNS Servers    


# These jails block attacks against named (bind9). By default, logging is off    
# with bind9 installation. You will need something like this:    
#    
# logging {    
#     channel security_file {    
#         file "/var/log/named/security.log" versions 3 size 30m;    
#         severity dynamic;    
#         print-time yes;    
#     };    
#     category security {    
#         security_file;    
#     };    
# };    
#    
# in your named.conf to provide proper logging    

# !!! WARNING !!!    
#   Since UDP is connection-less protocol, spoofing of IP and imitation    
#   of illegal actions is way too simple.  Thus enabling of this filter    
#   might provide an easy way for implementing a DoS against a chosen    
#   victim. See    
#    http://nion.modprobe.de/blog/archives/690-fail2ban-+-dns-fail.html    
#   Please DO NOT USE this jail unless you know what you are doing.    
#[named-refused-udp]    
#    
#enabled  = false    
#port     = domain,953    
#protocol = udp    
#filter   = named-refused    
#logpath  = /var/log/named/security.log    

[named-refused-tcp]    

enabled  = false    
port     = domain,953    
protocol = tcp    
filter   = named-refused    
logpath  = /var/log/named/security.log    

# Multiple jails, 1 per protocol, are necessary ATM:    
# see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/37    
[asterisk-tcp]    

enabled  = false    
filter   = asterisk    
port     = 5060,5061    
protocol = tcp    
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages    

[asterisk-udp]    

enabled  = false    
filter   = asterisk    
port     = 5060,5061    
protocol = udp    
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages    


# Jail for more extended banning of persistent abusers    
# !!! WARNING !!!    
#   Make sure that your loglevel specified in fail2ban.conf/.local    
#   is not at DEBUG level -- which might then cause fail2ban to fall into    
#   an infinite loop constantly feeding itself with non-informative lines    
[recidive]    

enabled  = false    
filter   = recidive    
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log    
action   = iptables-allports[name=recidive]    
           sendmail-whois-lines[name=recidive, logpath=/var/log/fail2ban.log]    
bantime  = 604800  ; 1 week    
findtime = 86400   ; 1 day    
maxretry = 5
```

Why aren't the IPs being blocked?

Here is my `filter.d/sshd.conf`

```
# Fail2Ban filter for openssh
#

[INCLUDES]

# Read common prefixes. If any customizations available -- read them from
# common.local
before = common.conf


[Definition]

_daemon = sshd

failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:error: PAM: )?[aA]uthentication (?:failure|error) for .* from <HOST>( via \S+)?\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)s(?:error: PAM: )?User not known to the underlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sFailed \S+ for .*? from <HOST>(?: port \d*)?(?: ssh\d*)?(: (ruser .*|(\S+ ID \S+ \(serial \d+\) CA )?\S+ %(__md5hex)s(, client user ".*", client host ".*")?))?\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)s[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .* from <HOST>\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because listed in DenyUsers\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not in any group\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)srefused connect from \S+ \(<HOST>\)\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because a group is listed in DenyGroups\s*$
            ^%(__prefix_line)sUser .+ from <HOST> not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\s*$

ignoreregex = 

# DEV Notes:
#
#   "Failed \S+ for .*? from <HOST>..." failregex uses non-greedy catch-all because
#   it is coming before use of <HOST> which is not hard-anchored at the end as well,
#   and later catch-all's could contain user-provided input, which need to be greedily
#   matched away first.
#
# Author: Cyril Jaquier, Yaroslav Halchenko, Petr Voralek, Daniel Black
```

Output of `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  43.229.53.66         anywhere            
DROP       all  --  58.218.211.38        anywhere            
DROP       all  --  124.173.68.198       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  183.56.173.20        anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Include your filter.d/sshd.conf file so we know what filter is being applied to auth.log and sshd.log.

Comment: Could you also post the results from `iptables -L`?  Don't delete any lines; just obfuscate IP addresses if you must.

Comment: I have updated the original post. @AndrewDomaszek

Comment: I see no indication that the firewall rules match on port number. Include the output of `iptables-save` to remove any doubt. Also using `DROP` has some drawbacks. Using `-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset` generally works better than `-j DROP`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite possible that the `sshd.filter` does not match the lines you have.  The filter I have installed would not match those lines.   There is a `fail2ban-regex` utility that can be used to test your regex.  A multi-line string in the regex contains multiple regexes, one per line.

A regex like the following may match better.  I think the existing regex is not finding enough data.

```
^%(__prefix_line)sFailed \S+ for .*? from <HOST>(?: port \d*)?(?: ssh\d*)?
```

When testing you may have to define things like `__prefix_line` in the test script.  Then try matching some records extracted from your log file.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: @RaymondLuna  I've updated my response with a possible regex. You should test.